# Bootstrap 4, navbar fixed-top and other sticky-top elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky

Here the reproduction: https://jsbin.com/lawafu/edit?html,output

Is this a bug? A mistake? A problem? An unrealizable idea?

**Before scroll:**
[image: before]

**After scroll:**
[image: after]

**What I need**:

Obviously I need to see the sidebar when I scroll down the page, using padding-top of the body for the fixed-top navbar.

I'm using this code for the sidebar:

```
<div class="sticky-top">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Bootstrap `sticky-top` has no offset for the Navbar since it sets `top:0`. You can add a custom class to account for the Navbar height.

```
.sticky-offset {
    top: 56px;
}

<div class="sticky-top sticky-offset">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/QeJOvbYswd

---

**Related:** 
[Bootstrap 4 fixed top nav and fixed sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641293/bootstrap-4-fixed-top-nav-and-fixed-sidebar/49650313)

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem, but what if I apply sticky-top to `col` div? It doesn't work anymore: https://jsbin.com/bezozey/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes, this is because the col is a flexbox child, and will "stretch" by default. To resolve this add align-self-start to the col: https://www.codeply.com/go/CwQGCsIiiN

Answer (score 2):

Zim's answer was helpful, but did not work for me in Safari 12.0.1 on MacOS (Chrome 70 was fine, worked as expected).

I think this is because sticky-top has a top:0px value which was taking priority over the custom class added.

So instead I simply added:

```
.sticky-top{
  top:56px;
}
```

Which fixed it in Safari too. Additionally, there's no need to add the custom class to the div.

Comment: You guys just saved me a pile of time. Thank you!